# Every braid is a product of braid transpositions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, braid-groups

Let's start with a definition of an $n$-braid, as I understand them:

**Definition:** Let $n$ be a natural number. In $
    \mathbb{R}^2$, consider two collections of $n$ nodes $\{P_i\}$ and $\{Q_i\}$. Let the $P_i$ lie at the points $(x,y)=(0,i)$ and the $Q_i$ lie at $(a,i)$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}^+$. Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ to exist as a plane within $\mathbb{R}^3$. An $n$-braid is a collection of $n$ non-intersecting, finitely interlaced strands that start on the nodes of $\{P_i\}$ and move in the strictly positive $x$-direction toward the nodes of $\{Q_i\}$. A node is either the destination or beginning of exactly one strand.

Consider $\sigma_i$ to be the swapping of the $(i+1)$th strand over the $i$th:

[image]

Similarly, consider $\sigma_i^{-1}$ to be the swapping of the $i$th strand over the $(i+1)$th, so that $\sigma_i\sigma_i^{-1}$ is the identity braid. Assume composition is from left to right. How would we show that any $n$-braid is a composition of braid transpositions? An example being the rather complex pure ($P_i\mapsto Q_i$) 4-braid below, which is decomposed using the relation $\sigma_i\sigma_j=\sigma_j\sigma_i \iff |i-j|>1$:

[image]

This braid would then have braid word $\sigma_1^{-1}\sigma_2\sigma_3^{-1}\sigma_2^{-1}\sigma_3\sigma_1^{-1}\sigma_2\sigma_1^{-1}\sigma_2\sigma_3^{-1}$:

[image]

Any ideas about how one might go about proving that any $n$-braid is a product of transpositions? We can assume both relations hold, including $\sigma_i\sigma_{i+1}\sigma_i=\sigma_{i+1}\sigma_i\sigma_{i+1}$. I am rather against hindering the clarity of such a proof by relying on heavy calculus, so I would be most appreciative if someone could share their insight on how one might operate within the realm of algebra.

Answer (score 1):

The result is due to Artin. You can find a proof for instance in

*Birman, Joan S.*, [**Braids, links, and mapping class groups. Based on lecture notes by James Cannon**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/9781400881420), Annals of Mathematics Studies. 82. Princeton, N. J.: Princeton University Press and University of Tokyo Press. IX, 229 p.  (1975). [ZBL0305.57013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0305.57013).

Specifically, Theorem 1.8 which might to your taste since it is mostly algebraic.

Or, if you prefer, read a proof in section 5.3 of

*Prasolov, V. V.; Sossinsky, A. B.*, Knots, links, braids and 3-manifolds. An introduction to the new invariants in low-dimensional topology. Transl. by A. B. Sossinsky from an orig. Russian manuscript, Translations of Mathematical Monographs. 154. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). viii, 239 p.  (1997). [ZBL0864.57002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0864.57002).

Their proof is very geometric and intuitive, so maybe you do not like this.